# how do i get rid of extra array in python?

Tags: python, list

so my code is as follows:

```
  promotion = [[""], ["promotion applied"],[""]]
```

how do I make it go from there to this state:

```
 promotion = ["", "promotion applied", ""]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
>>> promotion = [[""], ["promotion applied"],[""]]
>>> [x[0] for x in promotion]
['', 'promotion applied', '']
```

with tuple unpacking:

```
>>> [x for x, in promotion]  # works only if all items are single-item sequences.
['', 'promotion applied', '']
```

Comment: whoops, I was that editor-in-error. Just noticed :)

Comment: @AdamSmith, No problem. rolled back :)

Comment: what about the promotion is = to [[""], ["","promotion applied", "", "value", ""], [""]] and I want it to be ["", "promotion applied",""]

Comment: @slopeofhope, So you want to get the first non-empty string, but empty-string if there are only empty strings?

Comment: it doesn't have to be the first non-empty string..any value i specify in this promotion applied

Comment: @slopeofhope, I don't understand `any value i specify in this promotion applied`.

Comment: @slopeofhope, Anyway, here's code that will return the first non-empty strings: http://ideone.com/DoiqzF